# Shared function has non-shared return type

Tags: motoko

Getting error `Shared function has non-shared return type` for returning `Item` for the `get` method.

How would one make Item `shared` or is there a better way going about returning properties/object

```
public type Item = {
    id: Nat;
    var name: Text;
};

actor Maas {
    var items: [Item] = [];

    ...

    public shared query func get(id: Nat) : async Item {
        return businesses[id - 1];
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just started getting into Motoko but I dug a little bit into documentation.

As I understood you need to make your type shared type (https://smartcontracts.org/docs/language-guide/language-manual.html#sharability)

```
A type T is shared if it is:

- an object type where all fields are immutable and have shared type, or

- a variant type where all tags have shared type
```

Since `var` is declares mutable variables (https://smartcontracts.org/docs/language-guide/mutable-state.html#_immutable_versus_mutable_variables)
The type becomes non shared type.

All there is need to be done is to remove `var` from the type `Item`

```
public type Item = {
    id: Nat;
    name: Text;
};

actor Maas {
    var items: [Item] = [];

    ...

    public shared query func get(id: Nat) : async Item {
        return businesses[id - 1];
    };
};
```

Comment: Whats the best way to have a mutable type field and return it? Is there a way to return it without having to make a whole new type or make the type all immutable?

Comment: I'm sorry, there is no need to assign business with let, the problem was something different in type Item you used `var name` and var is used for `mutable` variables, so the only thing you had to change was to remove `var`. I will update answer

Comment: @Gekctek updated my answer, hope you will find it more helpful.